# How do I get the HTML code of websites in arabic?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm using this code to get HTML:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$html = file_get_html("http://www.google.com/");
echo $html;
...
```

But, when I try to get the HTML of [this site](http://kaktos.ir), the response shows incorrect characters like this:

```
���moY�&�9����i�[S$%ٲ�9������l�l/���F"H�H�VDPJ����˲59��[��v���R�Vɖ3KY��_A����_�  ��so�1�N��T�E"#nܸ��s��=�  ��������?�?�������  ���|������0Vk��Z�2o��E۪  ү�XF�ny���;v�R�ܦ���F�Ƨe˷  ��g����{�������}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code for your `file_get_html` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573612/unicode-in-php)

Comment: I think this may have somethign to do with the file_get_html function.  Is it unicode aware?  file_Get_contents should be fine.

Comment: @TobyAllen I have a feeling it's from the Simple HTML DOM library, in which case it's simply a `file_get_contents()` call internally.  See line 76 of [this file](http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/simple_html_dom.php) for the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$content=file_get_contents('http://www.kaktos.ir');
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($content).'<code>'; 
?>
```

works for me..

this will echo the html tags anyway, 
if you just want to reproduce the page you obviously only need

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.kaktos.ir');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

before the opening

```
<?php
```

Or try to change the page encoding for reading it

if you plan to save the content into the database
I suggest to use table with utf8_general_ci collocation

Thanks